# Plotting elements from repeat in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a plot of the `(X0,Ujn)` points created in the `repeat` function. Is there a way to do this in R? Here is my code:

```
LaxFriedrichs <- function(X0,delx,delt,t){
  repeat{
    Uj <- sin(X0)
    U <- sin(X0+2*delx)
    Ujn <- (Uj + U)/2 + (Uj - U)*(t/(2*delx))
    X0 <- X0+delx
    t <- delt + t

    plot(X0,Ujn)

    if (X0 > 2*pi/40) break
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know beforehand the limits of your x and y axes in the plot?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most efficient implementation, but it at least gets all your points plotted (keeps appending to x and y list and then plots those points at the end):

```
LaxFriedrichs <- function(X0,delx,delt,t){
  all.x = c()
  all.y = c()
  repeat{
    Uj <- sin(X0)
    U <- sin(X0+2*delx)
    Ujn <- (Uj + U)/2 + (Uj - U)*(t/(2*delx))
    X0 <- X0+delx
    t <- delt + t

    all.x <- c(all.x, X0)
    all.y <- c(all.y, Ujn)

    if (X0 > 2*pi/40) break
  }
  plot(all.x, all.y)
}

LaxFriedrichs(.001, .001, .001, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter version that takes advantage of R's vector operations.

```
f <- function(x0, dx, dt, t0) {
  x <- seq(x0,2*pi/40,by=dx)
  t <- seq(t0,t0+(length(x)-1)*dt,by=dt)

  Uj  <- sin(x)
  U   <- sin(x+2*dx)
  Ujn <- (Uj + U)/2 + (Uj - U)*(t/(2*dx))

  plot(x,Ujn)
}

f(.001, .001, .001, .5)
```

Here, `x` and `t` are vectors, so `Uj`, `U`, and finally `Ujn` are calculated in one step, rather than in a loop.

One thing to note: in the original algorithm, at each step `Ujn` is calculated at `x` but `x+dx` is stored, so you end up plotting `Ujn(x)` vs `(x+dx)`. The approach here corrects that, so the x-axis is offset by `-dx`.